# Global redirect in php from something.com to www.something.com

Tags: php, redirect, global

I'm a .net developer and I've just started developing a site on PHP running on IIS7-fastcgi.

I was wondering if there is any way to write a global function to automatically redirect any request that comes to my site in the format

```
http://something.com/anypage.php 
to
http://www.something.com/anypage.php
```

You can do this in ASP.NET on the global.asax file. IS there any way to do this or set this condition in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so..but you can do this using .htaccess

(edited to include comment below):

or the iis7 equivalent I guess is what you want http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

Comment: Looks like the IIS7 version of .htaccess is called Web.config http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

Comment: I think there are mod_rewrite equivalents for IIS.  http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite+iis

Comment: And it looks like that link I gave even shows something to www.something as part of example

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in IIS by using the [URL Rewrite](http://iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1691)
 module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must have .htaccess in your root directory, that says :

```
Redirect 301 http://something.com/anypage.php  http://www.something.com/anypage.php
```

But im not sure if IIS supports .htaccess files :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "something.com") {
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.something.com" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```